# Why is this array not populated?

Tags: java, android, arrays, youtube, youtube-api

I have a function prettyPrint() that is supposed to populate an array with strings after conducting a Youtube search. When I try to access it from another activity with an ArrayAdapter, the app crashes and logcat is tells me that the array is null.

Here's the class where I define the method prettyPrint(), SearchYoutube.java (It's the last method):

```
package com.example.activity2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ResourceId;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Thumbnail;

/**
 * Print a list of videos matching a search term.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Walker
 */
public class SearchYoutube {


       public static List<SearchResult> searchListResults = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * Define a global variable that identifies the name of a file that
     * contains the developer's API key.
     */
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "youtube.properties";

    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;
    public static String [] ytstuff = new String[(int) NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED];

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
     * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
     *
     * @param args command line args.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the developer key from the properties file.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = SearchActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            properties.load(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                    + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
            // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
            // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
            // the interface and provide a no-op function.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

            // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
            String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

            // Set your developer key from the Google Developers Console for
            // non-authenticated requests. See:
            // https://console.developers.google.com/
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(queryTerm);

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            searchListResults = searchResultList;
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
     */
    private static String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

        String inputQuery = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter a search term: ");
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputQuery = bReader.readLine();

        if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
            // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
            inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
        }
        return inputQuery;
    }

    /*
     * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
     * title, video ID, and thumbnail.
     *
     * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
     *
     * @param query Search query (String)
     */
    public static void prettyPrint(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {

        if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {        }

        while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

            SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
            ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

            // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
            // item will not contain a video ID.
            if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();
                for (int i=0;i<25;i=i+2)
                {
                    for (int j= 1;j <26;i=i+2)
                    {
                        if (j-i == 1)
                        {
                ytstuff[i] = rId.getVideoId(); //first thing is video id
                ytstuff[j] = singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle(); //second thing is title
                        }
            }
        }
    } 


}
    }
}
```

Here's the activity where I call prettyPrint(), SearchActivity.java

```
package com.example.activity2;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;



public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    ListView lst;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_activity);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      Iterator<SearchResult> it = SearchYoutube.searchListResults.iterator();
      SearchYoutube.prettyPrint(it, query);
      lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,SearchYoutube.ytstuff);
      lst.setAdapter(adapter);
      lst.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
}
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int i, long l)
{
    TextView temp= (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this,temp.getText()+""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I have a hunch that I may be misinterpreting what exactly the Youtube API methods are doing. The code in SearchActivity works perfectly if I just create a string array and pass it into the adapter, so I'm thinking something is wrong with the SearchYoutube class.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but what is the `if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {        }` line doing exactly?

Also, you should really consider using a HashMap, which has a <Key,Value> system--that appears to be what you're trying to create with that wacky double for loop. This is a lazy diagnosis, but it'll make your code much more readable and _probably_ fix your problem.

Comment: The method was originally meant to print results and that would have printed "No results" or something to that effect. And no I do not have stack trace. Not entirely sure what that is. I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense to use a mapping construct, but right now I'm just trying to get some dummy data from Youtube onto the list and see it on the screen. Really just feeling out the Youtube API at this point.

Comment: Hmm, I think what I did is pretty simple. Just iterating over even positions, putting IDs in those and iterating over odd positions and putting titles in those.

Comment: "I think what I did is pretty simple"
no.
This is simple: a class called VideoMetaData which contains whatever you want, such as ID and Title

`
while(iteraterThing.hasNext()){
  if(some condition){
    VideoMetaData videoData = New VideoMetaData();
    videoData.setID(...);
    videoData.setTitle(....);
    listOfVideoData.add(videoData);
  }
}`

what you're doing is is essentially creating your own very crude data object which is extremely difficult to change, relies on unusual parameters (i and j), and runs very poorly (O(n^2)).
For the sake of your future endevers, change it.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was that what I did was easy to understand. Not that it's necessarily efficient or flexible, though I appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop never increments j but i by 2.

Comment: Good catch. Didn't solve my problem, but good catch nonetheless. My ArrayAdapter is still causing the program crash, behaving as if the string array is null.